# Reactive input?

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose my shiny app looks like this:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(radioButtons("Output", "Continuous or binary:",
                                c("Continuous" = "Continuous",
                                  "Binary" = "Binary"), 
                                selected = "Continuous"), 
                   numericInput("sigma_y", "SD of y:", 0.1,
                                min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.01),
                   numericInput("mean_y", "mean_y:", 0.1,
                                min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.01)),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I show sigma_y only if output==continuous and mean_y only if output==binary?

I tried adding  `if(input$Output=="Continuous")` but that does not work :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create the `numericInput`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(radioButtons("Output", "Continuous or binary:",
                                c("Continuous" = "Continuous",
                                  "Binary" = "Binary"), 
                                selected = "Continuous"), 
                   uiOutput("test")),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$test <- renderUI({ 
    if(input$Output=="Continuous")
    {
      numericInput("sigma_y", "SD of y:", 0.1,min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.01)
    }

    else if(input$Output=="Binary")
    {
      numericInput("mean_y", "mean_y:", 0.1,min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.01)
    }
    else
    {
      return()
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```